# How to load mapper xml files with wildcard?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

Mybatis(ibatis) can  load `typeAlliases` with `package` as

```
<typeAliases>
   <package name="com.my.example.bean"/> 
</typeAliases>
```

If so , how can I load mapper xml files also ? I hate I always need to add in `mybatis-config.xml` for every new xml mapper files as

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/A.xml" />
    <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/B.xml" />
    <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/C.xml" />
    <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/D.xml" />
  .......
</mappers>
```

I'd like to use with wildcard "*.xml" as

```
<mappers>
    <mapper resource="mybatis/mapper/*.xml" />
</mappers>
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyBatis can also load mappers (Interfaces) from a package, see the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers).

```
<mappers>
  <package name="org.mybatis.builder"/>
</mappers>
```

Of course this seems to require that you have the interfaces, too, and not just xml files. Don't know of any method to load all the XML files, if you have no Interfaces, though.

Comment: yes .. sir. I have mapper interfaces and I also added as you described but while running from my test classes ....`org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found):` output error was show. Am I need some addition settings ?

Comment: I doubt ... if mapper interfaces were load from mybatis, how can **mybatis** knows the **path** of my mapper xml files ?

Comment: My mapper interfaces and mapper xml files are not in the same directory. Moreover their names also different. Is it problem ?

Comment: In the end, they have to be in the same directory. The best way to seperate them for coding, is to put the mapper .xml files into your resources folder (and the correct subfolder, of course) and your source files into the correct .src folder, so that maven (hopefully you are using that or gradle) will put them toegether in the end.

Comment: OK .... Thank your sir. Now I am using with maven and I know what you mean. I created my mapper files at `resources > mybatis > mapper`. I don't wish to create as `com.mypackage.blah.blah` . This is inconvinent for me. So ,now I forget about this. Thank your for your answer and documentation link sir.

Comment: That doesn't have to be a problem, since you can use maven to map the resources -> mybatis -> maper directory to somewhere else in the resulting structure. Never needed to do this, so unfortunately I cannot help you there, but I'm quite confident that it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and I have resovled it with wildcard.

Is there a xml file for configure the sqlSessionFactory bean.append a property like `<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:sqlmap/**/*Mapper.xml"/>` ,

`classpath:sqlmap/**/*Mapper.xml` is your `mapper.xml`'s location,and delete all the mapper resource,thant's all.